# Byte Buddy - Handling cyclic references in generated classes

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm trying to generate runtime wrappers around classes in some class graph, but I don't know how to handle the situation when there is a cycle in the graph.
Imagine there's a class A that has a field of type B, but type B has a field of type A. I want to generate classes A' and B' so that class A' has a field of type B' and B' has a field of type A'.
In Byte Buddy the method "defineField" can receive a parameter of type TypeDefinition. I think there must be a way to define TypeDefinition for a type that isn't defined yet, but I cannot find it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define such a field with `TypeDescription.Latent` but this is at your own risk. Byte Buddy treats this as a specific, unvalidated use case as type redefinition is quite complex considering the interdepencdency.

Make sure that you do not load a type before defining the latent type properly. Also, you probably need to combine the two types into a single `DynamicType.Unloaded` via the `include` method. Furthermore, you should note that the `ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECT` strategy might not work if the VM in question validates the injected type eagerly. As you can only inject one type at a time, in circular type definitions, at least one type will always be missing at the time of injection the first type. Consider using the `ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER` strategy which does not suffer this limitation.

This said, you can do this without any problems but you can experience `VerifierError`s what is something that you are normally promised to not experience.