# Byte Buddy - how can make a field self type?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

It is necessary to describe the structure of this class

```
class A{
    private List<A> listA;   
}
```

tried the solution: [Byte-buddy: generate classes with cyclic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870944/byte-buddy-generate-classes-with-cyclic-types)

but it will lead to an error

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot resolve declared type of a
> latent type description:...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TargetType` as a reference for the currently generated type:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(Object.class)
  .name("A")
  .defineField("listA", 
      TypeDescription.Generic.Builder.parameterizedType(
          List.class, TargetType.class).build(),
      Visibility.PRIVATE)
  .make()
```