# Bytebuddy circular dependency Java

Tags: java, byte-buddy

```
Class A {
    private B bObj;
}

Class B {
    private A aObj;
}
```

I am trying to generate above classes using `bytebuddy` using `InstrumentedType.Default` but getting Invisible field exception. Could someone please explain in detail how to solve.

Below is a reference
[Byte-buddy: generate classes with cyclic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870944/byte-buddy-generate-classes-with-cyclic-types/44884603#44884603)

Comment: No sure what you mean by *invisible field exception*. Could you post your code and the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to revisit your classes and get rid of the cyclic dependency first. It is not a good design pattern to begin with.

Usually such constructs can be avoided when introducing a 3rd interface/class.